# Unknown format code 'x'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a program in Python and all the code looks good except when I run the program from the terminal I am getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "packetSniffer.py", line 25, in <module>
    main()
  File "packetSniffer.py", line 10, in main
    reciever_mac, sender_mac, ethernetProtocol, data = ethernet_frame(rawData)
  File "packetSniffer.py", line 17, in ethernet_frame
    return getMacAddress(reciever_mac), getMacAddress(sender_mac), socket.htons(protocol), data[14:]
  File "packetSniffer.py", line 21, in getMacAddress
    bytesString = map('{:02x}'.format, bytesAddress)
ValueError: Unknown format code 'x' for object of type 'str'
```

Here is the code for my entire program so far, would anybody be able to help?

```
import struct
import textwrap
import socket

def main():
    connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(3))

    while True:
        rawData, address = connection.recvfrom(65535)
        reciever_mac, sender_mac, ethernetProtocol, data = ethernet_frame(rawData)
        print('\nEthernet Frame: ')
        print('Destination: {}, Source: {}, Protocol: {}'.format(reciever_mac, sender_mac, ethernetProtocol))

# Unpack ethernet frame
def ethernet_frame(data):
    reciever_mac, sender_mac, protocol = struct.unpack('! 6s 6s H', data[:14])
    return getMacAddress(reciever_mac), getMacAddress(sender_mac), socket.htons(protocol), data[14:]

# Convert the Mac address from the jumbled up form from above into human readable format
def getMacAddress(bytesAddress):
    bytesString = map('{:02x}'.format, bytesAddress)
    macAddress = ':'.join(bytesString).upper()
    return macAddress

main()
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this is Python 3?

Comment: Seems to be from here: https://github.com/koehlma/snippets/blob/master/python/network/sniffer.py

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968090/python-3-4-unknown-format-code-x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the following code section, [format type](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) `x` does not expect string. It accepts integer. It then converts integer to its corresponding hexadecimal form.

```
# Convert the Mac address from the jumbled up form from above into human readable format
def getMacAddress(bytesAddress):
    bytesString = map('{:02x}'.format, bytesAddress)
    macAddress = ':'.join(bytesString).upper()
```

So if your bytestAddress is a string form of integer, then, you could do:

```
bytesAddress = '123234234'
map('{:02x}'.format, [int(i) for i in bytesAddress])
#map('{:02x}'.format, map(int, bytesAddress)) 
['01', '02', '03', '02', '03', '04', '02', '03', '04']
```

Further, if you want to process a pair of integers (in string form) to hexadecimal, then first transform `bytesAddress to

```
[bytesAddress[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(bytesAddress), 2)]
```

Comment: You can use python 3 to get rid of the error.