# ValueError: Unknown format code 'x' for object of type 'str' in python 2

Tags: python

I have this error `ValueError: Unknown format code 'x' for object of type 'str'`.
The probleme is the version of my python(python 2.7) but I can't upgrade it.
Someone has any idea how to execute this line of code in python 2.

```
map('{:02x}'.format, bytes_addr)
```

See bellow the two functions uses it.

```
map('{:02x}'.format, bytes_addr)
def get_mac_addr(mac_raw):
    byte_str = map('{:02x}'.format, mac_raw)
    mac_addr = ':'.join(byte_str).upper()
    return mac_addr


def format_multi_line(prefix, string, size=80):
    size -= len(prefix)
    if isinstance(string, bytes):
        string = ''.join(r'\x{:02x}'.format(byte) for byte in string)
        if size % 2:
            size -= 1
    return '\n'.join([prefix + line for line in textwrap.wrap(string, size)])
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basic_sniff1.py", line 80, in <module>
    main()
  File "basic_sniff1.py", line 54, in main
    eth = ethernet_head(raw_data)
  File "basic_sniff1.py", line 23, in ethernet_head
    dest_mac = get_mac_addr(dest)
  File "basic_sniff1.py", line 6, in get_mac_addr
    byte_str = map('{:02x}'.format, mac_raw)
ValueError: Unknown format code 'x' for object of type 'str'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unknown format code 'x'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38451592/unknown-format-code-x)

Comment: Thanks! I try it but is not working for me, I don't understand how to adapt to my two functions

Comment: Thanks! I try it but is not working for me, I don't understand, how to adapt his answer to my two functions. Because my functions receive at least two parameters ...

Comment: The solution was python 3